# How does emacsclient determine what XDG_RUNTIME_DIRS is supposed to be?

Tags: emacsclient

When I run `emacsclient` I get this error:

```
$ emacsclient .
emacsclient: Should XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/run/user/10030' be in the environment?
emacsclient: (Be careful: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is security-related.)
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Sure enough setting `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/run/user/10030'` and running again fixes the problem but I would like to automate this. I could try running once and parsing this error message but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it. How is `emacsclient` figuring it out?

Comment: If it's set, it's normally set to `/run/user/$(id -u)`, but normally, if this directory exists, `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` should be set. What OS (distribution, version) are you running and how are you logging in?

Comment: I am using gentoo prefix on top of CentOS, looks like the prefix unsets it. If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally either [`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir) is available and your operating system should arrange for it to be set when you log in, or `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` isn't available (by Unix time scales, it's a very modern thing). Usually, on most modern Linux systems, it's set by systemd.

If `/run/user/YOU_USER_ID` exists, it's extremely unlikely for it not to be a suitable value for `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. So you could add this code to your `~/.profile` or whatever sh script sets up the environment in which you run `emacs` and `emacsclient`.

```
if [ -z "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ]; then
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
  if [ -d "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ] && [ -w "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ]; then
    export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
  else
    unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
  fi
fi
```